# C#: What is the proper way to show a form for "frmMainForm" settings and disposing?

Tags: c#

Backdrop: There are two forms, the main application form and a form to edit various settings for the operations of main application.

What would be the proper way to show the frmSettings form and how to dispose it once clicked OK or Cancel in the actual frmSettings form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a Dialog would be better suited to your Settings "form."  There are subtle differences between a dialog and a form that would make the dialog easier to handle.  A return code indicating the button that was clicked makes dialogs useful.

Supposing that you used a dialog - a using statement could be used (off the top of my head):

```
using (DialogSettings dlgSettings = new DialogSettings)
{
  if (dlgSettings.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
```

}
}

If you insist on using a form then you would have to

- Instance the form
- show the form
- record whether ok or cancel was clicked to a form level variable (from within the forms ok/cancel button click code)
- hide the form
- save the recorded value from the form
- dispose of the form
- make use of the saved ok/cancel value

Comment: What characterizes the difference between a form and dialog? I'm a bit confused by what you meant by using a dialog instead of a regular form designed to handle settings.

Comment: A dialog will return a "DialogResult" telling you whether the user clicked "Ok" or "Cancel".  A form will not do that automatically.  If you need to know how the user responded use a dialog.

Comment: How would I go upon applying a DialogResult return on my frmSettings effectively turning it into a Dialog instead of just a regular ol form?

Comment: Those properties won't help you.  What they do is set default buttons to be pressed when the "Enter" and "Escapse" keys are pressed.  You might be able to add a dialog to your project and cut and paste your code/controls over, but this may have side effects...

Comment: ...If that fails then you'll have to start with a new dialog from scratch.  You could still use your form, but you'd have to follow my steps listed above.  Of course there's not enough room in these comments to give detailed help.

Comment: @Mitt, in the ok button event, set frnSettings.DialogResult to DialogResult.OK. In the cancel button event, set it to DialogResult.Cancel. 
Then, close the form in both events. Then, you can use ShowDialog and you will get the proper result.

Answer (score 1):

fyi, using "frm" is not a recommended part of the C# coding guidelines. [Microsoft prefers you don't use hungarian notation in .NET at all.](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/articles/361363.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
using (frmSettings s = new frmSettings() )
{
   if( s.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
   {
       //do work
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main application declare an instance and show it.

```
using(frmSettings settingsInstance = new frmSettings())
{
    settingsInstance.Show();  //or ShowDialog()
}
```

Then just close the form when done...